# Difference between CTypedPtrArray and CArray

Tags: c++, templates, mfc, containers

MFC has two similar templated container classes: [`CTypedPtrArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctypedptrarray-class?view=msvc-160) and [`CArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/carray-class?view=msvc-160).

`CTypedPtrArray` is supposed to be an array of typed-pointers, while `CArray` can be an array of any type (including pointers), and I see nothing in the documentation that suggest that `CTypedPtrArray` is any safer/faster/easier than a `CArray`.

Is there any meaningful difference between these two?

```
CTypedPtrArray<CPtrArray, CMyFoo*>  arrayOne;
CArray<CMyFoo*, CMyFoo*>            arrayTwo;
```

Comment: There's more than one, but the first and most important one might be that CTypedPtrArray let you specify its base class through the first template parameter where CArray always derives from CObject. The docs do also list hints about the advantages: "In addition, the CTypedPtrArray wrapper performs much of the casting that would be required if you used CObArray or CPtrArray."

Comment: Did you find out the answer?

Answer (score 1):

CArray uses memcpy_s to move elements so not compatible objects that require the constructor to be called. Always use CTypedPtrArray for storing objects derived from CObject.